# There is no extension able to load the configuration

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to load custom config but getting exception:

> 1/2 InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php
>
> There is no extension able to load the configuration for
> "cwiczenia" (in ..\app/config\config.yml).Looked
> for namespace "cwiczenia", found "framework",
> "security",...
>
> 2/2 FileLoaderLoadException
>
> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "cwiczenia" ...

**..\src\CwiczeniaDependencyInjectionBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration.php**

```
namespace CwiczeniaDependencyInjectionBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface{

public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('cwiczenia');
    
    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('teamName')->end()
        ->end();
            
    return $treeBuilder;
```

**..\src\CwiczeniaDependencyInjectionBundle\DependencyInjection\CwiczeniaExtension.php**

```
namespace CwiczeniaDependencyInjectionBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

class CwiczeniaExtension extends Extension
{
    protected function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container) 
    {
        $configuration = $this->getConfiguration($configs, $container);
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'cwiczenia';
    }
```

**..\app\config\config.yml**

```
cwiczenia:
    teamName: Lakers
```

**AppKernel**

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new SandersBundle\SandersBundle(),
            new CwiczeniaDependencyInjectionBundle\CwiczeniaDependencyInjectionBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'), true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Same exception if I remove Configuration.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually register extension class, how to do it is described here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#manually-registering-an-extension-class

Something like this:

```
//.....
class CwiczeniaDependencyInjectionBundle extends Bundle
{

  public function getContainerExtension()
  {
    if (null === $this->extension) {
        $this->extension = new CwiczeniaExtension();
    }
    return $this->extension;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and fix it.

To register an extension you need to have same name for bundle and you extension. So, if you wanna enable your extension as `cwiczenia`, your extension file must be named as `CwiczeniaExtention` and bundle must be named as `CwiczeniaBundle`.

Or if you don't wanna change your Bundle name (`CwiczeniaDependencyInjectionBundle`), you must rename your extension to `CwiczeniaDependencyInjectionExtension` and then it will be available to load the configuration as `cwiczenia_dependency_injection`.

Or you can manually register extension, as mentioned above by @helios

Comment: I find this being a much better answer as automatic registration is much better. I am following all the steps, correct bundle name, config, config root and the bundles should load automatically but in my case none of the bundles are loading. I am just wondering what the problem is. A gist here includes all details and the error when i run behat https://gist.github.com/bizmate/82b4694d53ac23eac315a032bf41e6a5

Comment: @Bizmate First of all your config.yml should be:

```yml
  my_reviews_reviews:
    google:
      places_key: '%env(GOOGLE_PLACES_KEY)%'
    yelp:
      key: '%env(YELP_FUSION_KEY)%'
    cache:
      expire: 604800 # 2 days
      enabled: true
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html#getting-and-setting-container-parameters-in-php > The used . notation is just a Symfony convention to make parameters easier to read. Parameters are just flat key-value elements, they can't be organized into a nested array

PS. Sorry markdown not available

Comment: the problem was that i was loading the bundle specific configuration in the services.yml i was loading in the Extension class through the YAML loader. I have used flex to start fresh and now i have ported everything and looks like it is working well