# There is no extension able to load the configuration for ... Looked for namespace "...", found none

Tags: php, symfony

**Introduction**
I know. There are a thousands of post on this exact topic, but somehow I still can't manage to fix this issue. I'm always getting the error

`There is no extension able to load the configuration for "first" (in /var/www/app/src/tzfrs/SpotifyBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/settings.yml). Looked for namespace "first", found none`

**Purpose**
I created a bundle and want to have custom configuration options, but since they are bigger than a usual file, I don't want to put it in the `config.yml`, but in my own file.

**Description**
My project structure for the bundle looks like this `/src/tzfrs/SpotifyBundle`

Inside the bundle I have created the files

- `./TzfrsSpotifyBundle.php`
- `./DependencyInjection/Configuration.php`
- `./DependencyInjection/TzfrsSpotifyExtension.php`
- `./Resources/config/settings.yml`

I have, of course, registered the Bundle in the `AppKernel`, and everything works fine so far with the bundle, except for the new config I want to add

Contents of `TzfrsSpotifyBundle`

```
<?php
namespace tzfrs\SpotifyBundle;

use tzfrs\SpotifyBundle\DependencyInjection\TzfrsSpotifyExtension;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class TzfrsSpotifyBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Contents of `/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php` (minimized to relevant info only)

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('first');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->booleanNode('secondary')->defaultTrue()->end()
        ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

Contents of `./DependencyInjection/TzfrsSpotifyExtension.php` (minimized to relevant info only)

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('settings.yml');
}
```

Contents of `./Resources/config/settings.yml`

```
first:
    secondary: false
```

**Ideas**
If any more questions come up or suggestions that won't work, I'll update this section with the info

---

- What I tried was the same this post here suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/36051719/2823419 but it didn't work. I got the same error.
- Then I tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35505189 meaning naming the root element like my bundle. Still the same error

Comment: I assume you have checked  the manual? http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html Your root node will be something like tzfrs_spotify That is how Symfony knows what the config values are for a specific bundle.  Maybe take a look at the framework bundle configuration file as well.

Comment: Yes, I checked that, but didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have everything spelled correctly and that your extension class is actually being called.  If you don't name the extension just right then it won't be loaded.  I just tested this and it works fine:

```
cerad_spotify:
    first:
        secondary: false

class CeradSpotifyBundle extends Bundle
{
}

namespace Cerad\SpotifyBundle\DependencyInjection;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('cerad_spotify');
        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('first')
                    ->children()
                        ->booleanNode('secondary')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end() // first
            ->end()
        ;
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}

namespace Cerad\SpotifyBundle\DependencyInjection;

class CeradSpotifyExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();

        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        VarDumper::dump($config);
     }
}
```